# Fix absolutely positioned element to top of viewport on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, absolute

I'm trying to combine the best of both worlds and accomplish what fixed positioning does when you set `top: 0` (appends to top of viewport) while keeping the element absolutely positioned so it scrolls horizontally with its parent element (doing this with fixed is problematic).

The catch is this is a table header so trying to hack my way through this with nested `divs` set to different positioning methods won't work here.

What I currently tried was keeping the table header with a position of `absolute` while calculating the distance of the top of the table from the top of the viewport within a scroll event listener:

```
const distanceToTop = this.headerElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
this.stickyHeaderElement.style.top = `${Math.abs(distanceToTop)}px`;
```

`this.headerElement` is the original table header that you can scroll past (does nothing) while the stickyHeader instance is where the smoke & mirrors occurs.

This current method is doing what I want it to... *however, it's incredibly hacky because as you scroll past the original table header and the sticky instance appends, the sticky header shakes due to all the DOM manipulation happening every time the event listener fires.*

*Since it's recalculating with the logic above.*

Question: Can I have an absolutely positioned **table header** element also append to the top of the viewport like fixed positioning allows? Is there a more efficient solution out there?

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is "**sticky**". There are already plenty of examples and solutions out there, just search for it :)

Comment: If I understand what you're looking for, you can just add `position: fixed` once the .top of the element is at the top of the viewport (or wherever you want the effect to be triggered).

Comment: @ingridly Yeah, the problem is that when the position is set to fixed AND you scroll horizontally, the appended table header does not scroll with the rest of the content. Absolute positioning **does** allow the table header to scroll horizontally with the content. Tricky situation.

Comment: Can you set the header as fixed like the sticky examples, then trigger on the horizontal scrolling to align the labels with their columns?

Comment: @Will That's an interesting thought. I have a feeling that doing that won't work because the moment I apply a position of `absolute` it overrides `fixed` and the appended header unappends from the top of the viewport.

Comment: Right. But as the window scrolls, I think you can adjust the left-margin of the table header in the fixed area.

Comment: @Will I see what you're saying. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @Will Unfortunately it doesn't work as well as you'd imagine. There is something buggy with tracking horizontal scroll events. When you scroll horizontally, the event listener does not fire at a consistent rate so as you're scrolling left/right the appended header "drags" as with each subsequent event listener call. If that makes sense. Basically a lag.

Comment: @jose Damn. I might try something tomorrow. This has me curious.

Comment: @Will I appreciate the interest. I'll update this post if I come up with anything better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are going for?

```js
let fixed = document.getElementById('fixed');

window.addEventListener("scroll", e => window.requestAnimationFrame( () => {
  fixed.style.marginLeft = -1 * window.scrollX + "px";
}));
```

```css
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}

#unfixed {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr id="fixed">
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
        <td>fibble</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>ffft</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr id="unfixed">
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>baz</td>
        <td>fibble</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>meow</td>
        <td>ffft</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You win the internet today, sir.

Answer (score -1):

Sticky Headers are simple when using Position:fixed.

```css
#header_container {
  background: green;
  height: 60px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

#header {
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_container">
  <div id="header">
    Header Content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    Content Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not that simple. If you read my question, I'm not looking to just append an element to the top of a viewport. That's easy enough. The problem is maintaining that behavior while **ALSO** having the appended header scroll **horizontally** with the rest of the table. Something that having a position of `fixed` does not let you do.